# error credentials on gvenzl/oracle-xe ARM colima docker

Tags: oracle, docker, datagrip, apple-silicon, colima

I'm trying to run an Oracle database on mac m1Pro ARM, so far, here are the steps i did :

Uninstalled colima and docker:

> brew uninstall colima docker

Uninstalled docker desktop and deleted all files related.

Installed colima and docker :

> brew install colima docker

Ran this command to execute colima :

> colima start --arch x86_64 --memory 4

Executed the docker run :

> docker run -d -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=azerty gvenzl/oracle-xe

Checked if my container was running :

> docker container ls

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS        PORTS                                       NAMES
8ffc237bc009   gvenzl/oracle-xe   "container-entrypoin…"   4 seconds ago   Up 1 second   0.0.0.0:1521->1521/tcp, :::1521->1521/tcp   intelligent_williams
```

used the integrated commands as mentioned [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe) in "Database users" part :

base : docker exec container name|id createAppUser your_app_user your_app_user_password [your target PDB]

I first tried that :

> docker exec 8ffc237bc009 createAppUser oracle azerty XE

But the SID XE wasn't recognized by the listener, then I did that
(default target is said to be XEPDB1)

> docker exec  8ffc237bc009 createAppUser oracle azerty

so far it returned that :

```
Session altered.


User created.


Grant succeeded.
```

I was pretty confident there, so I ran into DataGrip and did that:

[image]

[image]

Then this error happend:

[image]

At first I thought it was because of SID XEPDB1 so I just replaced it with XE and this error got to me, at this point I knew it was responding:

[image]

Now I can't figure it out because I checked if I was misstyping in caps or anything, tried multiple times to cmd+C and cmd+v to make sur, still wrong logons. if anyone has a clue, I'm up for it. if there is anything wrong with what I did, I would love to know !

Comment: Could you please try to replace the URL string with the following:
`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1`?

Comment: IT WORKED oh my god, Olga... how can i say thank you enough... I've been on it for the past 3 months...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS Olga M answered in the comment of my post, the fix was to replace the URL string:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XEPDB1`

or

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE`

to :

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XEPDB1`

hope my process helps ✅.

Thanks again Olga M !